# MagicalRecord with primaryRelationshipKey

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, magicalrecord

I have Entity UserProfile with attribute uId.
I receive users from web and add they in core data.
I want that if there is a user with his id in my base - he will be replaced.
I use tip https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki/General-tips 
But How can I set that I want to use primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first do a fetch request and check if there is a UserProfile with that uId.

If there is, then just update that UserProfile and save.

If not, then create a new UserProfile and save.